# Can't seem to find the syntax error

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am rendering my React app on my server, but I am getting an error when I trying to `renderToString`. The error I get is `markup = renderToString(<RouterContext {...renderProps}/>); SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

```
require('babel-register')({
  presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
})
var routes = require('./public/src/routes');
var React = require('react');
var renderToString = require('react-dom/server');
var match = require('react-router');
var RouterContext = require('react-router');

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  match(
    { routes, location: req.url },
     (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
       if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send(err.message);
      }
      let markup;
      if(renderProps) {
        markup = renderToString(<RouterContext {...renderProps}/>);
      }
      return res.render('index', { markup });
     }
  )
})
```

Comment: How are you transpiling your JSX?

Comment: I am using webpack. I updated my code (I added the top line)

Comment: Can I run npm start or do I need to do something with babel node?

Comment: https://stanko.github.io/setting-up-webpack-babel-and-react-from-scratch/ you need webpack, babel, and the appropriate plugins for babel to transpile JSX appropriately that guide should get you there.

Comment: I've already done all this on the react side, but the error occurs in my index.js of my node server.